# Incorrect Plot Color R

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I am using the following code to generate a plot:

```
library(plotrix)

dat_fn = "emptiness.csv"
storage_fn = "final/results/emptiness_values.png"
data <- read.csv(dat_fn, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

png(storage_fn)
sizeplot(data$PercentEmpty, data$PercentUniform, col = data$QuestionType)
legend("topleft", legend = levels(data$QuestionType), pch = "o", col = 
unique(data$QuestionType))
dev.off()
```

I should be getting two black points in the bottom left, and one red in the top right.  Instead, I am getting one black and one red in the bottom left, and one black in the top right.  (See graph below.)  I am completely stumped - what could be going on here?  I double checked my data three times, the data is not the problem.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVeOh.png)

My data is:

```
ColumnName  PercentEmpty    PercentUniform  QuestionType
D   0.0 5.155436407691911e-05   a
E   0.0 0.00030932618446151465  a
F   0.14146517502706604 0.09666443264422334 b
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your data? Pasting `dput(data)` into your question will give us all a copy/pasteable copy of your data.

Comment: Edited - thank you!

Comment: I can't replicate your problem - when I run your code on the data you shared I get the correct plot. Try restarting R, reloading your data, and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: I restarted R, reloaded my data, and restarted my computer and I still get the same plot.  This is very strange...

Comment: Hmmm, actually when I zoom in it looks like I can replicate the problem. If I replace `sizeplot` with `plot` it works fine. I think, internally, `sizeplot` is reordering the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the processing `sizeplot` does ends up reordering some points. You don't seem to be using `sizeplot`'s feature of automatically resizing points, so I'd recommend just using `plot` instead which works just fine.

If you do need sizeplot, here's a hacky work-around:

```
with(data, plot(PercentEmpty, PercentUniform, type = "n"))
with(subset(data, QuestionType == "a"), sizeplot(PercentEmpty, PercentUniform, col = 1, add = TRUE))
with(subset(data, QuestionType == "b"), sizeplot(PercentEmpty, PercentUniform, col = 2, add = TRUE))
```

[image]